# How to make a jquery Datatable array out of standard json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array, datatable, javascript-objects

Firstly I am a Total jquery/js newbee!
Then I Have a long json like this:

```
[
{
    "rulesrev": 74,
    "macaddr": "",
    "lat": "3543.03133N",
    "ip": "10.128.113.180",
    "clientname": "D-06-29",
    "relay0mask": "-1",
    "relay1stat": "-1",
    "clientid": 542,
    "bldname": "D_valiasr_zartosht",
    "uptime": "",
    "current": "",
    "temperature": "",
    "softver": "",
    "relay0stat": "0",
    "volume": "100",
    "hardver": " ",
    "relay1mask": "-1",
    "pic": "",
    "comment": " p",
    "lon": "05124.48299E",
    "rtt": "2012/08/15 23:20:55.0 (load=0.05) (mem=0.11)",
    "bldaddr": ""
},
{
    "rulesrev": 74,
    "macaddr": "00:10:f3:22:30:08,00:10:f3:22:30:09",
    "lat": "3537.41356N",
    "ip": "10.19.64.63",
    "clientname": "M-19-013",
    "relay0mask": "-1",
    "relay1stat": "-1",
    "clientid": 494,
    "bldname": "tarebar_m19",
    "uptime": "19d 20:05:12",
    "current": "",
    "temperature": "",
    "softver": "",
    "relay0stat": "0",
    "volume": "100",
    "hardver": " n",
    "relay1mask": "-1",
    "pic": "",
    "comment": " ",
    "lon": "05122.94431E",
    "rtt": "2012/08/25 09:19:25.0 (load=0.05) (mem=0.17)",
    "bldaddr": ""
}
]
```

and i want to convert it to a Jquery DataTable readable array which should be like this:

```
"aaData": [
            /* Reduced data set */
            [ "Trident", "Internet Explorer 4.0", "Win 95+", 4, "X" ],
            [ "Trident", "Internet Explorer 5.0", "Win 95+", 5, "C" ],
            [ "Trident", "Internet Explorer 5.5", "Win 95+", 5.5, "A" ],
            [ "Trident", "Internet Explorer 6.0", "Win 98+", 6, "A" ],
            [ "Trident", "Internet Explorer 7.0", "Win XP SP2+", 7, "A" ],
            [ "Gecko", "Firefox 1.5", "Win 98+ / OSX.2+", 1.8, "A" ],
            [ "Gecko", "Firefox 2", "Win 98+ / OSX.2+", 1.8, "A" ],
            [ "Gecko", "Firefox 3", "Win 2k+ / OSX.3+", 1.9, "A" ],
            [ "Webkit", "Safari 1.2", "OSX.3", 125.5, "A" ],
            [ "Webkit", "Safari 1.3", "OSX.3", 312.8, "A" ],
            [ "Webkit", "Safari 2.0", "OSX.4+", 419.3, "A" ],
        [ "Webkit", "Safari 3.0", "OSX.4+", 522.1, "A" ]
        ],
        "aoColumns": [
            { "sTitle": "Engine" },
        { "sTitle": "Browser" },
            { "sTitle": "Platform" }
]
```

what should i do?
I can not find any post here or elsewhere to describe something like this
  can anyone help?
**EDIT**
the second array is just a structure i saw in [datatables](http://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html)
example. and i want to change my json to a structure like the second array
**EDIT:**
  in my json the first part of each data will make the table column header that will go to the bottom of second array structure and the second part which is the values goes to the second array structure top part. and finally it should looks like this:

```
      "aaData": [
[ 74, "", "3543.03133N", "10.128.113.180", "D-06-29", "-1", "-1", 542, "D_valiasr_zartosht", "", "", "", "", "0", "100", "", "-1", "", " p", "05124.48299E", "2012/08/15 23:20:55.0 (load=0.05) (mem=0.11)", ""],
[ 74, "", "3543.03133N", "10.128.113.180", "D-06-29", "-1", "-1", 542, "D_valiasr_zartosht", "", "", "", "", "0", "100", "", "-1", "", " p", "05124.48299E", "2012/08/15 23:20:55.0 (load=0.05) (mem=0.11)", ""],
[ 74, "", "3543.03133N", "10.128.113.180", "D-06-29", "-1", "-1", 542, "D_valiasr_zartosht", "", "", "", "", "0", "100", "", "-1", "", " p", "05124.48299E", "2012/08/15 23:20:55.0 (load=0.05) (mem=0.11)", ""],
[ 74, "", "3543.03133N", "10.128.113.180", "D-06-29", "-1", "-1", 542, "D_valiasr_zartosht", "", "", "", "", "0", "100", "", "-1", "", " p", "05124.48299E", "2012/08/15 23:20:55.0 (load=0.05) (mem=0.11)", ""],
[ 74, "", "3543.03133N", "10.128.113.180", "D-06-29", "-1", "-1", 542, "D_valiasr_zartosht", "", "", "", "", "0", "100", "", "-1", "", " p", "05124.48299E", "2012/08/15 23:20:55.0 (load=0.05) (mem=0.11)", ""],
[ 74, "", "3543.03133N", "10.128.113.180", "D-06-29", "-1", "-1", 542, "D_valiasr_zartosht", "", "", "", "", "0", "100", "", "-1", "", " p", "05124.48299E", "2012/08/15 23:20:55.0 (load=0.05) (mem=0.11)", ""],
[ 74, "", "3543.03133N", "10.128.113.180", "D-06-29", "-1", "-1", 542, "D_valiasr_zartosht", "", "", "", "", "0", "100", "", "-1", "", " p", "05124.48299E", "2012/08/15 23:20:55.0 (load=0.05) (mem=0.11)", ""],
[ 74, "", "3543.03133N", "10.128.113.180", "D-06-29", "-1", "-1", 542, "D_valiasr_zartosht", "", "", "", "", "0", "100", "", "-1", "", " p", "05124.48299E", "2012/08/15 23:20:55.0 (load=0.05) (mem=0.11)", ""],
[ 74, "", "3543.03133N", "10.128.113.180", "D-06-29", "-1", "-1", 542, "D_valiasr_zartosht", "", "", "", "", "0", "100", "", "-1", "", " p", "05124.48299E", "2012/08/15 23:20:55.0 (load=0.05) (mem=0.11)", ""],
[ 74, "", "3543.03133N", "10.128.113.180", "D-06-29", "-1", "-1", 542, "D_valiasr_zartosht", "", "", "", "", "0", "100", "", "-1", "", " p", "05124.48299E", "2012/08/15 23:20:55.0 (load=0.05) (mem=0.11)", ""]
    ],        "aoColumns": [
{ "sTitle": "macaddr" },
{ "sTitle": "lat" },
{ "sTitle": "ip" },
{ "sTitle": "clientname" },
{ "sTitle": "relay0mask" },
{ "sTitle": "relay0stat" },
{ "sTitle": "relay1stat" },
{ "sTitle": "clientid" },
{ "sTitle": "bldname" },
{ "sTitle": "uptime" },
{ "sTitle": "current" },
{ "sTitle": "temperature" },
{ "sTitle": "softver" },
{ "sTitle": "volume" },
{ "sTitle": "hardver" },
{ "sTitle": "relay1mask" },
{ "sTitle": "pic" },
{ "sTitle": "comment" },
{ "sTitle": "lon" },
{ "sTitle": "rtt" },
{ "sTitle": "bldaddr" },
 ] 
 ]
```

Comment: Please improve your example, in your initial JSON, there's no mention of "Trident" or "Internet Explorer 4.0". How are we supposed to know where those values came from?

Comment: You're still not explaining how your initial JSON maps to the JSON for datatables. For example `[{a:"Trident", b:"IE"}, {a:"WebKit",b:"Safari"}]` would map to `[["Trident","IE"],["WebKit","Safari"]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no magic way. You have to iterate through your original object and create an object in the format expected by datatable.

Suppose you want three columns on your table

> rulesrev,macaddr,lat

You could use the following code to generate the data in the format required by datatables http://jsfiddle.net/vZVUc/

```
var originalJson = [{...}]; // Your JSON blob

// You can't rely on the order of iteration of properties in your JSON object,
// so you have to specify which fields you want
var columns = ["rulesrev", "macaddr", "lat"];

// If you don't care about the order of properties, you can generate columns 
// using the following
var columns = [];
for (var propName in originalJson[0]) {
  columns.push(propName);
}

var dataTableObj = {
   aaData: [],
   aoColumns: []
};

// Stuff the aoColumns array
for (var i=0; i < columns.length; i++) {
    dataTableObj.aoColumns.push({sTitle: columns[i]})
}

// Stuff the aaData array
for (var i=0; i < originalJson.length; i++) {
    var row = originalJson[i];
    var dataTableRow = [];
    for (var j=0; j < columns.length; j++) {
        dataTableRow.push(row[columns[j]]);
    }
    dataTableObj.aaData.push(dataTableRow);
}

// Now you can pass it to your datatable
$('#example').dataTable( dataTableObj );
```

If you're adventurous you can use [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) (supported in later browsers only, but easy to create a shim for). http://jsfiddle.net/vZVUc/1/

```
// You can't rely on the order of iteration of properties in your JSON object,
// so you have to specify which fields you want
var columns = ["rulesrev", "macaddr", "lat"];

var dataTableObj = {
   aaData: originalJson.map(function(row) {
      return columns.map(function(col){
          return row[col];
      })
   }) ,
   aoColumns: columns.map(function(col){
      return {sTitle: col}
   });
};
```

<strike>This isn't tested, so there are probably bugs, but it should teach you how to do it.</strike>  See http://jsfiddle.net/vZVUc/1/ and http://jsfiddle.net/vZVUc/ for examples

Comment: thanks so much. it shows you really deserve your 18k reputation. can you introduce some sources to me to study js arrays and objects? it will be your kind. thanks again

Comment: The best place is here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object Just beware that some of the functionality won't work in older browsers, but they suggest shims for all the newer functionality.