# Converting JSON to have a new top-level wrapper

Tags: javascript, json, mustache

I suspect I am using the wrong terminology, so please bear with me.

I have been using mustache.js very effectively to work with the JSON output of an API. I am working with a sibling API that has outlook that looks mostly similar, excepting that there is no top-level name. I am trying to figure out how to adjust the new JSON output into the other format, such that I can continue using my mustache.js approach (this seems like the easier of the options, the other being using something other than mustache.js, which I am seeking to avoid).

I can use mustache.js to iterate very easily over the following JSON body using the top-level name 'records':

```
{"records":
[{"dt_created":"08/23/2013 04:49:13 PM","created_by":"x,   x","dt_updated":"08/23/2013 04:49:13 PM","updated_by":"x, x","field_60374":  ["Project 67"],"field_60331":["Ability to adjust the number of lines dynamically based on   the mood of the person 3 rows down, 4th cube, 11th building. A breakthrough in mind-control   data processing."],"field_60333":   [{"id":"x","first":"x","last":"x"}],"field_60394":  [{"id":"x","first":"x","last":"x"}],"field_60414":["11"],"field_60375":  ["22"],"field_60395":["A"],"record_id":"1920704","form_id":"10898"},
{"dt_created":"08/23/2013 04:47:45 PM","created_by":"x, x","dt_updated":"08/23/2013 04:47:45 PM","updated_by":"x, x","field_60374":["Project 2"],"field_60331":["Very cool project to allow more than a single invoice to be in an ERP at any one time. Quite a big leap forward."],"field_60333": [{"id":"x","first":"x","last":"x"}],"field_60394": [{"id":"x","first":"x","last":"x"}],"field_60414":["x,  x"],"field_60375":["60"],"field_60395": ["A"],"record_id":"1920703","form_id":"10898"}],
"meta":{"total":2,"count":2}
}
```

The format that I can't iterate through, since it is missing a top-level name, is:

```
[{"id":"x","user": {"id":"x","first_name":"x","last_name":"x"},"title":"Test Post 3","text":"This is an equally cool and enthralling post.","created_at":"2013-08-29T17:46:04.801Z","updated_at":"2013-08-29T17:46:04.804Z","num_comments":0,"num_likes":0},
{"id":"y","user":   {"id":"212342277","first_name":"x","last_name":"x"},"title":"Test Post 1","text":"Super cool content you want to read!","created_at":"2013-08- 29T17:44:58.188Z","updated_at":"2013-08-29T17:44:58.190Z","num_comments":0,"num_likes":0}]
```

I tried the following to massage the second JSON example into the format of the first:

```
$.ajax({
     […….],
     success: function(json_data){
                        alert("success");
                             var template=$('#listPosts').html();
                        var stuff = {"records":json_data}; //here
                        var stuff = JSON.stringify(stuff); //here
                        alert(stuff);
                           //var html = Mustache.to_html(template, json_data);
                        var html = Mustache.to_html(template, stuff);
                        //$('.content-pane').empty();                                                                                                                               
                        $('#listOfPostsContainer').html(html); 
}
}
```

I have an alert that pops up with what is in var 'stuff', and it seems to be formatted like the first JSON example, but mustache.js doesn't parse it (I have verified mustache.js executes). Before trying to address any other issues, I wanted to understand if how I am adding a top-level name to the JSON array in the above AJAX call success attribute is correct, or if I have to do it differently.

If I am missing something to help explain this, let me know, so I can add it.

Comment: What is `JSON.stringify` doing in there? Mustache wants a JS object, and `JSON.stringify` is turning it into a string. Ditch that line and it'll likely work.

Comment: I figured there was something wrong.

I actually, after much further googling, finally connected with the right post. I can get around my issue - in this circumstance, by using (.) in mustache such that I iterate over the second JSON response thus:

    {{#.}}
    [.....]
    {{/.}}

I appreciate you taking the time to read this. Figures as soon as I give up and post a question I would figure it out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert a JSON string to a JSON string with a different structure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14289044/how-to-convert-a-json-string-to-a-json-string-with-a-different-structure)